# CGRectIntersectsRect tolerate some points before reaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, 2d, 2d-games

I am making a reaction game, where you can destroy enemys and earn points, but if the enemy nodes intersect the players node, it reduces the lives by one.
Its a reaction game so I want to give some tolerance points in the intersection. So if they are intersecting, I don't want to see immediately a reduction.

Here is my code:

```
 if (CGRectIntersectsRect(enemy.frame, player.frame)) {
    lives--;
}
```

My goal is a tolerance threshold for the intersection.
I hope someone can help me. (code in objective c please)

Comment: have you tried simply reducing the size of either enemy.frame or player.frame for that purpose? If you make them smaller, the hit will be detected "later"

Comment: if you're using SpriteKit, then I would highly recommend using the built in physics engine for collisions, through `SKPhysicsBody`. I would also agree with luk2302, just reduce the size of the physics body.

Comment: i won't work because I would need a changing physicsbody for my game and that is impossible. @luk2302 what do you mean with making the frame smaller ? do you mean the image ? But that wouldn't be what I am looking for..

Comment: The suggestion being made by luk2302  is you produce two new rectangles which are inset from the two frame rectangle and test intersection of those.

Comment: @CRD can you give me a code example ?

Comment: Lookup `CGRectInset`.

Comment: @CRD I didnt found good examples..

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on the question I'm guessing you are not understanding what "inset" means.

If you have a rectangle with origin (10,20), width 100 and height 50 then if you inset the rectangle by 10 on the x-axis and 5 on the y-axis the result is a rectangle with origin (20,25), width 80 and height 40.

Note that the inset rectangle is contained within the original rectangle. @luk2302 suggestion is instead of testing whether the frame rectangles of your two objects intersect you test whether two smaller rectangles intersect. You can generate these smaller rectangles by insetting the frame rectangles by some amount.

You can of course calculate an inset rectangle directly with a few lines of code, but there is an API call `CGRectInset` (and also `NSInsetRect`) which will do it for you in one line.

HTH

Comment: Okay now I understand what it means, but I still don't know how to implement this CGRectInset at same time with CGRectIntersectsRect to detect overlapping.. Sorry for all this noobness..

Comment: ?? If you have a variable `x`, a function `sqroot`, and a function `sin` how do you calculate the `sin` of the `sqroot` of `x` and put the result into `ans`? (1) `tmp = sqroot(x); ans = sin(tmp);` or more directly (2) `ans = sin( sqroot(x) )`. Now you have two functions, two rectangles, and you want to combine them...